# Fuzziness Setting and Meaning Matching Results in Elasticsearch in Laravel

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

My query is

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "match": {
            "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "text": {
              "query": "everyone happy everywhere world passing smile each other ",
              "fuzziness": "auto"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "mood": {
              "value": 0
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This query brings results that I don't want e.g it brings the result of "passing", and "laughing" etc, that matches with "looking". I don't want this result because thinking meaning is not as looking.
How can I use this to make my query perfect?

My other question is that how to use other settings of fuzziness? as mentioned here

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html

**Sample Document:-**

```
 {
    "_index": "halohas",
    "_type": "haloha",
    "_id": "5f30e7f06a471c4b6f2a2062",
    "_score": 33.891895,
    "_source": {
        "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
        "text": "everyone happy everywhere world passing smile each other ",
        "mood": 0
    }
}
```

**Complete Results fetched after Query execution:-**

```
    {
    "took": 39,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 65,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 33.891895,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f30e7f06a471c4b6f2a2062",
                "_score": 33.891895,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "everyone happy everywhere world passing smile each other ",
                    "mood": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f302c47fc8df5755934bdc2",
                "_score": 11.912707,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "everywhere travel across world. ",
                    "mood": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f30e53c26221a3dd218f872",
                "_score": 7.974513,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "smile woman ",
                    "mood": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f309f583e9990674e171532",
                "_score": 7.534701,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "world ",
                    "mood": 2
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f2ff3cd9f6786088b7921f2",
                "_score": 7.3043556,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "smile children’s face ",
                    "mood": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f30547f2242bf327e522f62",
                "_score": 6.908468,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "seeing daughter happy!   ",
                    "mood": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f3070b3fddcb3760c7ae0b2",
                "_score": 6.65074,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "light passing through leaves trees   ",
                    "mood": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f2fff5a9fbf4b57e555f935",
                "_score": 6.35747,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "mother’s smile!❤️ ",
                    "mood": 2
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f30b59eab885429c2038ec2",
                "_score": 6.0646305,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "view books bield top each other rusty book store library ",
                    "mood": 1
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f3092a6882b0d22d60b1722",
                "_score": 6.017489,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "beach  ",
                    "mood": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f2ff3de73a23c19f93f3f82",
                "_score": 5.895053,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "backs children’s heads lean each other huddle together.  ",
                    "mood": 2
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f30ad854091a30e3748fdc3",
                "_score": 5.57206,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "seeing family happy  ",
                    "mood": 2
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f301a99e7cb3021676cf692",
                "_score": 5.4925385,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "visual. world view—caring each every life, human animal our endangered planet. ",
                    "mood": 5
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f3008c0a24a46138446c862",
                "_score": 5.419055,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "beach.  ",
                    "mood": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f30787a146697320a25d872",
                "_score": 5.2449656,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "family laughing happy life. ",
                    "mood": 2
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f30556285641664f5356e93",
                "_score": 5.0532618,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "sunset empty beach ",
                    "mood": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f30869486887c18161209b2",
                "_score": 5.025687,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "sunset beach ",
                    "mood": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f2ff3b87934fc7d967281a3",
                "_score": 5.025687,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "looking beach  ",
                    "mood": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f2ff7167ec00a1b337f7912",
                "_score": 4.970048,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "everywhere nature ( sunrise sunset, big forest, lacs,...) ",
                    "mood": 2
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f303b163ad86065d66d7a42",
                "_score": 4.66111,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "anything see when wake each day. ",
                    "mood": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f302acde20297713727cc42",
                "_score": 4.6264167,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "top mountain beautiful nature SMILE PURE JOY! ",
                    "mood": 2
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f303c2f8ee4d36b8f2f9ae2",
                "_score": 4.584092,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "Sunsets beach mountains  ",
                    "mood": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f2ff378c4e8fa76245101d2",
                "_score": 4.5512257,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "beach ",
                    "mood": 2
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f30451546d06c525e596bb2",
                "_score": 4.5171666,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "Everyone’s view valid ",
                    "mood": 2
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f304d0ec17ebb51cf7c5042",
                "_score": 4.4749317,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "beach!  ",
                    "mood": 2
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f3067020e7dcd4de95ec1f2",
                "_score": 4.4749317,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "beach ",
                    "mood": 5
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f3078b26134b228b303d432",
                "_score": 4.4749317,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "beach ",
                    "mood": 5
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f30b8746d302079dc0871a3",
                "_score": 4.419055,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "beach.  ",
                    "mood": 2
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f30115aa7e6c30006304e02",
                "_score": 4.391369,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "yard, sitting outdoor furniture got response COVID. It's great see people passing reminded better times. ❤ ",
                    "mood": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f309f66fd669a03a227f6f2",
                "_score": 4.352552,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "beach night city lights  ",
                    "mood": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f30217d42d3341bb92d2203",
                "_score": 4.3382063,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "beach.   ",
                    "mood": 5
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f3053d801715f7aef4dcbb2",
                "_score": 4.2747197,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "classy sunset beach think. ",
                    "mood": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f30077d93afb8280769fae2",
                "_score": 4.2183633,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "beach sunny, cold day. ",
                    "mood": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f2ff81321dbe134fd2937f2",
                "_score": 4.081563,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "ocean .. beach  ",
                    "mood": 2
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f3096f6b7320e6ec90aa232",
                "_score": 4.025687,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "sunset beach  ",
                    "mood": 2
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f2ff4b38c9d562a32727532",
                "_score": 4.0101357,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "seeing smile back me ",
                    "mood": 2
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f307080ade1a513cd40a452",
                "_score": 3.9633794,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "ocean beach chair Wailea hawaii ",
                    "mood": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f2ff9f085d5283247093482",
                "_score": 3.958018,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "beach flowers ",
                    "mood": 2
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f30e8546a471c4b6f2a2063",
                "_score": 3.9078517,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "beautiful, glowing happy human beings ♡♡♡ ",
                    "mood": 2
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f304e781b5cb35f64366a12",
                "_score": 3.6833045,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "lovely house hill where see mountains one direction ocean other.  ",
                    "mood": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f2ff9d06edfec7975469562",
                "_score": 3.6531332,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "depth ocean realising there’s world meets eye.  ",
                    "mood": 2
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f304ce31ebdbd15ea0615e2",
                "_score": 3.6202354,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "sunset other things feel aesthetically pleasing ",
                    "mood": 1
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f30106a86c55a3c6c1bb9d2",
                "_score": 3.5213587,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "sunset/ sunrise beach! ",
                    "mood": 2
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f30216d2cb9fb5ee210c9b2",
                "_score": 3.4342415,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "any beach atop mountain peak after long hike ",
                    "mood": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f2ff922744c620d364ebb02",
                "_score": 3.3832874,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "golden skyline sunset beach ",
                    "mood": 1
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f305e6b4a36e908d67c9fe2",
                "_score": 3.3832874,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "beach & boy end future ",
                    "mood": 4
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f3037d7c7521c22011e5f52",
                "_score": 3.3651414,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "walking Disney World Park every 2-3 years when go. big thunder lightning rain storm.  ",
                    "mood": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f30a05fe74f7079c567e4d2",
                "_score": 3.3139935,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "when people really, truly happy. happen often. love seing rare moments. ",
                    "mood": 2
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f3091f3d61586331052ea52",
                "_score": 3.282056,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "choosing see world through beautiful eyes notice appreciate wonder ",
                    "mood": 2
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f3014203d90fb35702b5dc2",
                "_score": 3.2747197,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "beach all times day ",
                    "mood": 2
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f2ff99422b91302ed05f434",
                "_score": 3.2183633,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "sun setting beach house  ",
                    "mood": 2
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f2ff5d8363d2e2d00643863",
                "_score": 3.1735876,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "beach house see ocean sun. also room’s night see moon sun wakes :) ",
                    "mood": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f302141b30a31596f364e12",
                "_score": 3.1166856,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "sea summer house beach  ",
                    "mood": 6
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f2ffa1e3aaeb079ae33c3a2",
                "_score": 3.0938876,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "kids playing beach while relax.  ",
                    "mood": 6
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f30724a35795129da1580f2",
                "_score": 2.9633794,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "looking out over beach water  ",
                    "mood": 2
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f302325a082044a4b271642",
                "_score": 2.8774018,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "site seeing nature....*I wrote wanted read other beautiful halohas ♥️* ",
                    "mood": 3
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f2ff3a1ccc30a1f054bb3d4",
                "_score": 2.6802943,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "sunset beach stars mountain top  ",
                    "mood": 2
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "halohas",
                "_type": "haloha",
                "_id": "5f3001608007db1d155f9222",
                "_score": 2.6797404,
                "_source": {
                    "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a",
                    "text": "dog laying floor sleeping peacefully it’s view little world s bd grateful it. ",
                    "mood": 2
                }
            }                }
        ]
    }
}
```

**This is mapping**

```
{
    "halohas": {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "haloha_id": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "lat": {
                    "type": "float"
                },
                "location": {
                    "type": "float"
                },
                "long": {
                    "type": "float"
                },
                "mood": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "pin": {
                    "properties": {
                        "location": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "text": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add mapping for `mood`, `filtered text`? Definitely `thinking` ll not match `looking` because of only `fuzziness`? Because maximum edit allowed is 2 by default. Can you add a sample document also.

Comment: fuzzyness will make `looknig` match `looking` or things of this sort of nature. It will definitely not make `looking` match `thinking` can you share the analyzer you are using on that index?

Comment: @apokryfos I just updated my question hope this will help you to understand

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you have all those results is not because fuzzyness but because of `operator` of the [match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html). If you don't include the operator the default is `OR` which will match a document that contains any of the words you provided.

To make the search more strict use `AND` as the operator:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "match": {
            "haloha_id": "5f2f33c2c6f0fc27e725ee8a"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "text": {
              "query": "everyone happy everywhere world passing smile each other ",
              "fuzziness": "auto",
              "operator": "AND"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "mood": {
              "value": 0
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You can alternatively use `minimum_should_match` to set the minimum number of words that must match for a result to be included instead of changing the operator

Comment: It's a strict search :) but for a learner it would solve the problem. Am I correct?

Comment: @Gibbs for some use cases it's necessary to match all terms included. It's not clear what the use case is here but from what OP asked it seems like they do want to match the whole phrase

Comment: I completely agree. `text.keyword` also a right option in this case.

Comment: it is still matching passing with laughing in case minimum_should_match:1

Comment: `minimum_should_match` means it should match at least one word which is what you had without `minimum_should_match` . If you wonder why you get results when you don't expect them try using the [explain](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html) endpoint